# How do I prevent more than one alert, confirm or prompt popping up in a mousemove function?

Tags: javascript, alert, mousemove

I have my JS code like this:

When you move the mouse very fast, there would be more than on alert box. So I tried to add some varible in the callback function of mousemove. But the problem still exists, what should I do?

```js
var has_alert=false;
$('div').on('mousemove',function(){
  if(has_alert) return;
  has_alert=true;
  alert(2)
  has_alert=false;
})
```

```css
body {background:red}
div {background:white; width:500px;height:500px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test content</div>
```

Comment: remove `has_alert=false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt`. These all spawn a modal window, which temporarily inhibits processing of other pending (mousemove) events. By the time the second event is handled, the first event handler is already finished, the dialog box has closed, and `has_alert` is already back to false. It seems impossible to tell the difference between events fired *before* the dialog box was opened, and *immediately after* the dialog box was closed.

One solution is a delayed reset of `has_alert`:

```js
var has_alert=false;
$('div').on('mousemove',function(){
  if(has_alert) return;
  has_alert=true;
  alert(2)
  window.setTimeout(function() { has_alert=false; }, 20);
})
```

```css
body {background:red}
div {background:white; width:500px;height:500px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><body>

<div>test content</div>
</body>
```

Another solution is to completely abandon `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt`, and use HTML-based dialogs instead. IMHO that's a design decision you won't regret in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the `setTimeout` suggestion. It works perfect.